# Looking for some examples of ambiguous sentences with compound particles

Tags: grammar

For writing a text book, I am looking for some ambiguous sentences with compound particles.

As an illustration, consider my attempt as follows.
Recall that when の and に are combined, it results in a new particle のに, so there is a possibility to make ambiguous sentences with のに.

- の can be used to nominalize clauses. For example: **お酒を飲まないの**
- Nに　can also be needed for some expressions.  For example:  **アニメに**興味がある

Now I have to find sentences with pattern XのにY such that they can be read in two ways:

- Xのに、Y　--> Even though X, Y
- XのにY

> タバコは吸わないのに興味がある。

It can be interpreted in 2 ways:

- タバコを吸わないのに、興味がある。Even though I don't smoke, I am interested in smoking.
- タバコを吸わないのに興味がある。I am interested in not smoking. (the speaker must be a smoker.)

## Questions

Could you give me other better examples?

Comment: The object for 興味がある is missing if you use を instead of は after タバコ in the sentence meaning "even though I don't smoke, I'm interested in". Usually, 吸わないけれど or 吸わなくても is used in this case, not のに.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following:

> 健気**にも**生きる人達。
> 健気に + も + 生きる / 健気 + にも + 生きる
>
> それ**では**何も起こりません。
> それでは / それ + で + は
> *(the former might seem uncommon but a GM of TRPG would say that)*
>
> それ**でも**勝てる。
> それ + で + も / それでも

Or I'm not sure whether this famous example is what you want though:

> ここ**では**きものを脱いでください。
> ここ + で + はきもの / ここ + で + は + きもの